# Getting time difference for unique values in photo feed using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, time, timestamp, converters

I am working with a dynamic feed that pulls in recently uploaded photos along with the timestamp of when it was posted. Currently the timestamp is in milliseconds. I have a script that subtracts the posted timestamp value from the integer value of the current time. It then formats the remainding integer value into a time string. Ultimately producing a string of "...posted x minutes ago" (where x is the difference in time). See JS below:

```
function toSeconds(time_str) {
    // Extract hours, minutes and seconds
    var parts = time_str.split(':');
    return parts[0] * 3600 +
    parts[1] * 60 +
    +
    parts[2]; // seconds
}

//GETS CURRENT EPOCH VALUE & CONVERTS TO TIME STRING
var d = new Date(); 
var currentEpoch = (d.getTime()-d.getMilliseconds())/1000;
var currentTime = new Date(currentEpoch *1000);
var currentDate = currentTime.toLocaleTimeString({hour12: false});

//GETS EPOCH VALUE OF POST & CONVERTS TO TIME STRING
var postEpoch = $(".timestamp").html();
var postTime = new Date(postEpoch *1000);
var postDate = postTime.toLocaleTimeString({hour12: false});

//GETS THE DIFFERENCE
var difference = Math.abs(toSeconds(currentDate) - toSeconds(postDate));

//FORMAT THE DIFFERENCE
var result = [
Math.floor(difference / 3600)
Math.floor((difference % 3600) / 60)
];

result = result.map(function(v) {
return v < 10 ? '0' + v : v;
}).join(':');


//INJECT DIFFERENCE INTO TIMESTAMP DIV
$(".timestamp").html("posted" + result + " minutes ago");
```

Each image is contained in its own div along with a nested div for the each timestamp. See sample HTML:

```
<div class="imgContainer">
    <img>
    <div class="timestamp">1385537546</div>
</div>

<div class="imgContainer">
    <img>
    <div class="timestamp">1385536903</div>
</div>

<div class="imgContainer">
    <img>
    <div class="timestamp">1385537273</div>
</div>
```

My script seems to be working right, but the problem is that this functionality only works on the very first timestamp div. So the first image will have the correct time value, but the rest of the images inherit the same exact value instead of getting their own unique value. I realize the solution may be throwing in a (this) somewhere, but I am stumped.

Comment: you apply the timestamp to a class '$(".timestamp")', so you apply it to all div's which contain this class. When is this function fired? On page Load or on some event?

Comment: May be because of the same class name , try using unique id

Comment: @Maksym - the ".timestamp" div is being dynamically added as well. Each image gets pulled in with the HTML format I have posted. The script is getting called on page load

Comment: @Bharath - I cannot give each div a unique ID. The timestamp div gets pulled in dynamically with the image

Comment: @NickJ , can you show the function which load's the images?

Comment: I added an answer using class , check it

Comment: @Maksym - I am using http://instafeedjs.com/ plugin. If you check it out, I have manipulated the "templating" to include a div the pulls in the timestamp for each individual image.

Comment: @NickJ where do you get `time_str` and how is it being stored. can you provide the exact initialization function you use for the plugin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understood from the plugin you can do this:
1. Use

> mock (true/false) - Fetch data without inserting images into DOM. Use
>   with success callback.

and

> success (function) - A callback function called when Instagram returns
>   valid data. Takes the JSON data as an object argument.

So basically I overridden the default rendering for each image and inserted a custom item instead.

You can read more about it [HERE](http://instafeedjs.com/#advanced)

**Javascript**

```
var feed = new Instafeed({
    pages: 1,
    limit: 5,
    get: 'tagged',
    tagName: 'thetypein',
    clientId: '467ede5a6b9b48ae8e03f4e2582aeeb3',
    mock: true,
    success: function (json) {
        for (var i = 0; i < json.data.length; i++) {
            var cont = $("<div>")
                .addClass("imgContainer")
                .appendTo($("#instafeed"));
            var img = $("<img>")
                .attr("src", json.data[i].images.thumbnail.url)
                .appendTo(cont);
            var time = $("<div>")
                .addClass("timestamp")
                .attr("id", "Time_" + (i + 1))
                .text("Added " + CountTime(json.data[i].created_time)+" minutes ago")
                .appendTo(cont);
            }
        }
    });
feed.run();
```

Also I've modified your function in order to use it properly and fixed your `toSeconds` function:
**Javascript**

```
function CountTime(posttime) {
    function toSeconds(time_str) {
    // Extract hours, minutes and seconds
        time_str= time_str.replace("AM","").replace("PM",""); // added to get rid of "AM" and "PM" 
    var parts = time_str.split(':');
    return parts[0] * 3600 +
    parts[1] * 60 +
    +
    parts[2]; // seconds

}
    var d = new Date(); 
var currentEpoch = (d.getTime()-d.getMilliseconds())/1000;
var currentTime = new Date(currentEpoch *1000);
var currentDate = currentTime.toLocaleTimeString({hour12: false});
    console.log(currentDate);
var postEpoch = posttime;
var postTime = new Date(postEpoch *1000);
var postDate = postTime.toLocaleTimeString({hour12: false});
    console.log(postDate);

    var difference = Math.abs(toSeconds(currentDate) - toSeconds(postDate));
    console.log(toSeconds(postDate));
    var result = [
Math.floor(difference / 3600),
Math.floor((difference % 3600) / 60)
];

    result = result.map(function(v) {
return v < 10 ? '0' + v : v;
}).join(':');
    return result;
};
```

Here is an example [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/V2GPA/25/)

**UPDATE 1**

After a discussion with Bharath Rallapalli and a small research I've found Out that you should read more about [toLocaleTimeString()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleTimeString), because it can wary depending on browser and culture settings on user PC and cause problems.

Comment: Hey guys thanks for the update! This is looking really nice. Just a couple questions. I'm looking at the fiddle an am seeing the Instafeed function has two places where options are added. FOr example, the "mock" is set to false in one place and true in the other. Also, it's set to sort by most recent, but the time of posts look to be scattered. Other than that I'm loving this!